# problems when installing django-inventory

Tags: python, django

that's what shows when i'm trying to install django-inventory
{python version 3.9}
{pillow version 8.2.0}
at the beginning of the Error :

```
Running setup.py install for Pillow ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

at the end of the Error :

```
Rolling back uninstall of pillow
```

because of the length of the Error i couldn't write it all.
so please can anybody help me :(

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about this django-inventory https://pypi.org/project/django-inventory/ I guess the problem is that this project wasn't updated for over 6 years and does only support Django 1.6 .

So I do not recommend using it. Maybe you can describe why you want to install it and then we can see if there's another package that's currently maintained and therefore a better fit for you.

A general rule of thumb of choosing packages is to always look at the code repository. There you can easily see if the project is currently maintained.